# Report screen position after refresh

Tags: abap

I have a report in ABAP.

After start selection I write the result with 'Write' command. I have many lines so it exceeds the screen height. I also have a refresh button in menu. When I refresh the page it writes the whole screen again. But the problem is that; before refresh I scroll down to 5000th line, after refresh it writes everyline again but the screen goes to the first line.

I want screen to stay where it was before refresh.

Thanks.

Comment: ...how about using an up-to-date mechanism to display data instead of `WRITE`...? :-)

Comment: you are always telling this to me. I (an unexperiented ABAP programmer) should do it like this right now.  I will update my self soon. Thanks :)

Comment: If you're being told to use outdated technologies: That's not educating people, that's the exact opposite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the first line of the list in [`sy-staro`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABENSYSTEM_FIELDS.htm) and use [`SCROLL LIST`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/de/ABAPSCROLL.htm) to change the position after updating the list.